# will wcf handle return values (of big sizes) on different connection speeds?

Tags: c#, performance, wcf, connection, size

I've checked the net and so far I couldn't find what exactly i'm looking for. Here is my question:
let assume that we have a wcf service which returns a simple text or even an object( a class ).if we have increased the maxreadsize, Quotas sizes and etc to maximum values to avoid couple of errors, and the size of the return values be more than the "speed" of net connection ,will wcf manage to transfer the entire return value on its own?
example:

speed is 20kbps and the return value,is a class whose size is 30 kb ..will wcf transfer it in 2 sec or something ?(assuming timeout values are also set to right amounts).
im pretty confused on this, please guide me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well it goes as fast as it goes.
If your payload is actually 30.000 bits (and not bytes) you'll get it over the wire in 2 seconds on a good day.
But of anything disturbs the session, like another application also using bandwidth or you have packet loss, big latency or problem with the connection you will fail.

This is not specific to WCF but to all network communication.
Depending on the WCF configuration you may have more or less serialization overhead that can make the transmitted size larger than the "raw" data size.

The only way to know for sure is to make extensive testing. You can use [Fiddler](http://www.fiddler2.com/fiddler2/) with a [plugin](http://www.logic-worx.com/index.php/tools-and-apps/fiddler-connection-simulator/) or another tool to simulate slow network connections.

Comment: what did you mean exactly by  "fail " u mentioned,so the wcf doesn't manage to send it again  on next try or something? ..the thing is I don't care about the time it takes to transfer the information..what I really want to know is what exactly will happen when the speed is not sufficient to transfer a class or string ,for example as the return value of  " string  get_string()" when it's being called by the client? i.e, if the connection is stable but slow, will it be done eventually?

Comment: You will fail in transmitting the data in two seconds.
If you send a new 30kb package every two seconds and your connection can't handle the speed you will eventually fill your TCP buffer. I'm actually not sure what problem you run into, either you get some exception or your memory consumption will grow with queued messages. It some point your connection will be contended enough to give you all sorts of timeouts and other weird stuff.